# Opencv : Cannot open display : C++, Raspberry Pi Headless connection

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have got an error :

> Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

1. Below is the simple image display program in opencv using C++ and in raspberry pi 3 Model B
2. I understood " Imshow " function which create a window to display image in GUI will not work in terminal
3. I am using headless connection (with LAN connection - SSH through Putty, raaspberry pi desktop access through VNC )

Code:

```
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv ;
int main() {
    Mat img = imread("/home/USER/Pictures/python.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    imshow("opencvtest",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Getting the error:

```
$ g++ -ggdb pkg-config --cflags opencv -o basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp opencvtest.cpp pkg-config --libs opencv

$ ./opencvtest
```

> " (opencvtest:1927): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display"

Just help me running a simple program and let me know how can i achieve this . I am newbie to raspberry pi .

Thanks
Atila

Comment: what is your desktop environment?  You could use X11 forwarding on PuTTy.  Install XMing for Windows (i assume windows because of PuTTy)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command, prior to the execution of the application.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the revert Mike . I have tried using the same command as mentioned  but neither i got error nor solution                                                                 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export DISPLAY=:0.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./opencvtest



pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export DISPLAY=:0.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./opencvtest

Comment: No output and system is idle

Comment: Have you verified that the X windows system is running on Raspberry Pi? Also are you sure you are monitoring the correct virtual terminal? You could try the chvt 7 command in order to check the corresponding vt.